# Command line load-time weaving

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj

So I am starting with AspectJ and have a problem. The following example works perfectly in Eclipse but when I try to run it in bash - it does not work.

This is my code I will monitor:

```
public class TestClass {
  public static void method1() {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    method1();
  }
}
```

This is my Aspect class:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

    @Aspect
    public class LogMe {
        @Pointcut("call(public* TestClass.*())")
        public void metCall() {}

        @After("metCall()")
        public void aftercallAdvice() {
            System.out.println("Blah");
        }
    }
```

What I do is create jar called 'apsects.jar' with `META-INF/aop-ajc.xml` with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aspectj>
        <aspects>
                <aspect name="LogMe"/>
        </aspects>
        <weaver options="-showWeaveInfo"/>
</aspectj>
```

I try to run it like that:

`java -javaagent:/home/tdi/dev/test/aspectjweaver.jar -classpath "aspects.jar;/home/tdi/dev/test/aspectjrt.jar" TestClass`

What I get is:

`Error: Could not find or load main class TestClass`

How can I run this application with LTW aspects ?

Comment: this is a classpath problem. where is the compiled TestClass.class? most likely you are missing a stage where you need to call javac, to compile the class files, and ajc to compile the aspects.

Comment: TestClass.class is in the working directory, where I run java command. Aspects are compiled into jar file. I do not need to call ajc because I use annotated AspectJ

Comment: just add a "aspects.jar;/home/tdi/dev/test/aspectjrt.jar;." - edit (windows path separator)

Comment: @aepurniet adding '.' does not change anything.

Comment: well im stumped. does 'java TestClass' find the class? if you cant then its a classpath problem. if you can then its something with the weaver agent.

Comment: @aepurniet when I run without agents, the class works well. when I add -classpath modifier then it does not find TestClass.class

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be a problem that TestClass is not in the JAR-file together with the aspects. You could try to put a folder `META-INF` with your `aop-ajc.xml` into the working directory with TestClass.class.

Another option would be to compare your run command with that of eclipse. You can do this be running the project in Debug mode, then right click on the process and open its Properties. Then you can see how eclipse is running the project on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue, then I run below command follow the steps in this url [flylib.com](https://flylib.com/books/en/2.927.1.32/1/) , then it worked

```
java -javaagent:"/Users/XXX/test/aspectj/lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar" -classpath .:lib/aspectjrt-1.8.13.jar com.XXX.aops.AOP5.HelloWorld
```